# ssrs report viewer vs exported pdf page count

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, count, export

The number of pages displayed when viewed in ReportViewer and in exported PDF are differing.
Eg: 50 records are shown in one single page of Report Viewer. But when Exported to PDF 45 reords come in page 1 and the remaining come in page 2.

Soution Tried: 
1)Removed Top and Bottom Margins.
2)Reduced "Interactive Page Size" to match the page count.
But it is not consistent, as it is behaving differently with different number of records.

Can anyone tell me how should I proceed to achieve sync between the ReportViewer and exported PDF ?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you've checked the Body size matches the doesn't exceed the Page Setup size in any dimension?

Comment: Your **Interactive Size** should be **PageSize - (minus) Margins**. Remove any borders. I don't think you'll be able to match exactly because of all the differences between rendering on a screen and in a PDF.

Comment: Hi Jonnus I have checked and Body size is lesser than Page Size.
I also tried removing the Page Height and Page Width attributes. Still it didn't work.

Comment: Hannover, Is "Interactive Size = PageSize - Margins" the closest I can get to achieve this sync ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - you can't do what you are trying to do: the different renderers handle pagination differently, but appropriately for their output.

The HTML renderer is optimised for screen-based reading and generally allows more content per page than the print renderer does as the print renderer is constrained by the paper size that it formats to. Thus the HTML renderer allows more content on fewer pages for a better browser experience whereas the print and PDF renderers have to conform strictly to the page length.

The best illustration of this is the Excel renderer - the Excel renderer renders the entire report onto a single worksheet in most cases (for reports with grouping and page breaks set on the group footer it will render each group on its own worksheet). You wouldn't want the Excel renderer to artificially create worksheets to try to "paginate" your report or to put it all in one worksheet but insert the header into the spreadsheet rows every "page". It does the appropriate thing which is to include all the data in one big worksheet even though that may be logically thought of as one big "page".

The HTML renderer page length is determined (more accurately, influenced) by the [InteractiveHeight](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154635.aspx) attribute of the report (in the InteractiveSize property in the Properties pane for the report). However, the interactive height is an approximation rather than a fixed page break setting and your page breaks may still not conform to the print version even if you set InteractiveHeight to the same length as your target page length. This is because the HTML renderer will vary the page length to group the data together better so the interactive page breaks happen around about, but not always exactly, where the interactive height is set.

This is what is happening in your scenario where the report viewer shows 50 records on one page but the PDF has 45 on the first page and 5 on the second page. The report viewer is making the decision that since there are only a few records left to display it will just include them all on the one page rather than force the user to scroll even though the interactive height will be exceeded. Thus you get a better user experience but a variance in pages between renderers. The important thing about the report is the data and the experience with working with that data in that renderer, not that the pages are the same length no matter how you look at it.

See [this discussion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677573.aspx) of rendering behaviour for more information on why what you are trying to achieve isn't achievable. Just educate your users that the browser pagination is optimised for their viewing pleasure.

Comment: Hi Chris thank you for your response.

Is "Interactive Size = PageSize -  Margins" the closest I can get to achieve this sync ??
Please let me know if I can improve the sync in any other way. If not perfectly sync'd.

Comment: Yes, but it still won't be perfect because the actual rendered height will vary from the interactive height according to how the renderer feels it is best to display your data